# Is bad/good/optionnal to defined vars after created them?

Tags: javascript

Reading the code of many javascript libraries, I see that many developers use to set variables as soon as they were created them.

```
var i = 0,
var c = 0;
```

I prefer instead to defined vars after created them.

```
var i,
    c;

i = 0;
c = 0;
```

But there might be an explanation about why this or that way?

Comment: In a function scope , a var declaration is always put at the top of the function ,so wether you declare them inline or not it doesnt matter , they will always be declared like you did the second way when the script is executed.

Comment: @camus I would vote your comment as the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's purely style. Some people prefer to have their declarations isolated from initialization, others like to do it in one. To the JavaScript engine, they're actually identical, because it handles `var` prior to the first line of code of the function actually executing. (Note how that is different from some other languages.) That is, it quite literally treats your two examples identically: First it creates `i` and `c` with the value `undefined`, and only later when it starts executing the step-by-step code of the function does it set `i` to 0 and then `c` to 0. (This is covered in some depth in Section [10.4.3](http://es5.github.com/#x10.4.3) and Section [10.5](http://es5.github.com/#x10.5) of the spec.)

For me, as long as I stick with simple values, I like to do them in one (although I always used to be a "purist" about keeping them separate; I did a lot of silly things when I was younger). But I try to avoid complex logic in the initialization. Sometimes I find I've written half my function as a series of comma-delimited statements starting with `var`, and that starts to get hard to read and maintain so I tend to pull them out at that point.

On the other hand, a reason to keep them separate is it gives you plenty of room to comment them. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Both would work, but if you define your variables without initializing them, and use them before initialization, that's bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

It is because they will be using conditions to set the initial value like :

```
var i;

... code ...

if(b==something){
    i = somevalue;
}

... code ...

a = i + b;
```

and when b is not equal to something, the variable would still be undefined. To prevent this becoming a problem in later usage, they give an initialization value to variables.

But if you are directly setting the initial value after defining it, there won't be any difference. Like the others say, it's for compactness and good readability and style.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a matter of preference.  I've used both.  With complicated code, the second example is better, as long as the coder is using descriptive variable names.  I like to think of it as informing the reader that I'll be using these variables, so watch out for them.

Another consideration is scope.  Make sure you're declaring your variables in the right scope (global/class/function/etc).  If you declare them too narrowly, you'll inadvertently create two different variables (which can be insanely difficult to debug).  If you declare them too broad, it could reduce program efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

You can even use this style:

```
var a = b = 0;
```

Initializing variables in the definition prevents errors caused by the variables are not set and have the initial JavaScript default value of `undefined`.

Comment: Note that in code with 'use "strict", an error will be thrown for 'undeclared variable b'